# How to find date wise history of commands being fired

Tags: bash, history

How can I make the history command display the date and time information in addition to the command line?

Comment: This depends on your shell. Bash's history file _.bash_history_ for example doesn't contain any date information, it is just a list of commands.

Comment: @scai, it depends on the `HISTTIMEFORMAT`, it *may* contain date information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The history of executed commands is stored by your shell. Try adding something like this to you `~/.bashrc`

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m/%d - %H:%M:%S: "
```

It will change the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable and bash will store a timestamp in its history accordingly. Then your history will look like this

```
487  08/16 - 16:12:01: cd Downloads
488  08/16 - 16:12:04: ls -a
489  08/16 - 16:12:37: cat README | less
490  08/16 - 16:12:58: pkg-config --list-all | grep webkit
491  08/16 - 16:13:04: history
```

Available identifiers are

```
%d - Day
%m - Month
%y - Year
%T - Time
%H - Hours
%M - Minutes
%S - Seconds
```