# How to store date, time, and the user's IP in Bash history

Tags: bash, shell, history

I need to re-setup history command to show both date, time and the IP address of user's from where they logged in to our server and execute a particular command. Is there any way to show these info with the history command?

The Sample Output would be:

`Sat 04 Nov 2017 06:20:20 AM +03 111.111.111.111 : pwd
 Sat 04 Nov 2017 06:20:20 AM +03 111.123.123.111 : mkdir test
 Sat 04 Nov 2017 06:20:20 AM +03 123.123.44.32   : pwd`

Help me to setup these changes via either .bash_profile or .bashrc

Comment: On a CentOS server(Forget to mention)

Comment: Please show your efforts.  You can see this post to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987761/how-to-find-date-wise-history-of-linux-commands-being-fired

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already enter this entry on .bash_profile and it shows date, time correctly. But unable to fetch out the IP address of users who execute those commands.

entered below code in .bash_profile

export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%c : "

Output is :
Sat 04 Nov 2017 06:24:35 AM +03 : history

I need output as :

Comment: Sat 04 Nov 2017 06:20:20 AM +03 123.123.44.32   : pwd

Answer (score 1):

Though you can turn timestamps on in Bash history by setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT`, you cannot prefix a string to every line of the history file. You could use the DEBUG trap to achieve your goal, by maintaining your own history file:

```
save_history() {
  # make sure IP is set in .bash_profile instead of capturing it each time here
  printf '%s : %s : %s\n' "$(date)" "$IP" "$BASH_COMMAND" >> /path/to/history_file
}

trap save_history DEBUG
```

This way, the `save_history` function gets called before each command and it records the history in the file.

---

See also:

- [How to run some command before or after every Bash command entered from console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585397/bash-run-some-command-before-or-after-every-command-entered-from-console)

Comment: Hi @codeforester

Thanks for your answer, but I didn't quite understand well.
Please provide the exact steps to accomplish this output to find out IP, date with history command. 

Once again thanks. :)

Comment: Use a combination of `ss` and `grep` to extract the IP.  And understand that SO is not a free code writing service.  You need to put your effort.